# Tomcat seems to start but no process is running

Tags: linux, tomcat

In installed Tomcat 8.0.21 on /opt. When I run the startup.sh the following output is displayed. However, no Tomcat process (8080) is running and the wars I copy on webapps are not unzipped. Ideas?

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/jdk1.8.0_45/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.21/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Comment: What logs says?

Comment: org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler

Comment: Solved with: sudo mkdir /var/www/webservices/l3dmgr/output